# Connection string for postgresql that runned on docker

Tags: c#, postgresql, docker, asp.net-core, connection-string

I have an ASP.Net Core app on my local machine that uses postgresql. So I need to connect my postgresql database running in a docker container.
I connect to this db with pgAdmin, but when I set the connection string on my app and run the command `dotnet ef database update`, it shows the following error

```
IPv4 address 0.0.0.0 and IPv6 address ::0 are unspecified addresses that cannot be used as a target address.
```

My connection string looks like this

```
host=0.0.0.0;port=54320;database=mydatabase;user id=postgres;password=mypassword
```

Comment: the ip address is not correct , use localhost or 127.0.0.1 instead

Comment: `0.0.0.0` isn't a valid IP. Databases don't need any special syntax when they run inside docker. You need to find out what port the database listens to, even if you run Docker locally. A container has to be configured *explicitly* to expose internal ports to external traffic.